# Redshift: TRUNCATE TABLE IF EXISTS

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, truncate, drop-table

It is [recommended](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TRUNCATE.html) to use `TRUNCATE TABLE` instead of `DELETE`. However, truncate table does not support the `IF EXISTS` clause. The alternative is to `DROP TABLE` and recreate but needs DDL. Is there a way to do `TRUNCATE TABLE` if only the table exists?

Comment: I know nothing about redshift, but I would look at try catch end catch in SQL...

Comment: Do you have any problem with just running `TRUNCATE`, even if it generates an error? Or will that stop a script from running? Also, why do you think the table might not exist? If it doesn't exist, you can't do anything with it anyway, so your script would fail too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options to achieve it:

**SQL Procedure/Script**

Using `IF` condition, checking if table exists, then only truncate your table.

**With Plain SQL Statements**

Use `Create` table with `if not exists` in combination with `Truncate`, this will ensure table always exists & your consecutive SQL statements don't error out & stop.

```
CREATE TABLE @tobetruncated IF NOT EXISTS
TRUNCATE TABLE @tobetruncated
```

> NOTE: This is not specific to REDSHFIT, mostly applies to all DB unless it supports special functions (like one I know Oracle has `TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION`). Truncate is like a all or nothing operation, and thats what makes it much better in performance than DELETE.